# How to permanently change the file/directory permission

Tags: linux, files, permissions, directory, chmod

How do I change the permission of file/directories such that I am able to create, edit, delete them anywhere in my system? Currently, I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried:

```
sudo chmod 777 -r /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

...after installing **Xampp** but it does not seem to work for the `htdocs` folder.

Comment: `chmod 777` is never the right thing. What are you trying to do? You probably need to set the ownership or add a group permission on this file. What user/group does xampp run as?

Comment: Permanent? It can be non permanent?

Answer (score 6):

Setting open permissions like this is usually the wrong thing to do. What leads you to believe it is the solution you want? What are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens? Do you have Apache configured and running, or do you just want local access to the `xampp` docs? Whatever the case, it seems as if setting permissions to 777 is a bit of a sledgehammer approach.

Beyond that, your `chmod` syntax is incorrect:

```
chmod -R 777 /path
```

The `-R` flag goes *before* the mode specification, not after it. It is also probably a capital `R` and not a lower case `r` (but I don't use Linux so don't take my word on that - look at the manpage to get all the gory details).

Answer (score 1):

First try to find the permission that you have for this folder and its subsequent files using this command:

```
ls -lrt
```

Try to see if there is a sticky bit associated with it. Then change to root using:

```
sudo su
```

And then give permission as:

```
chmod +rwx filename
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Read logs `/var/log/apache2/` to see why apache was failing to display web pages for you.

On Ubuntu, default apache DocumentRoot directory is `/var/www`. (I think you can change the DocumentRoot directory by editing a file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and restarting apache.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put files in there, then either change the permissions so that YOU have write access, or use sudo. DO NOT EVER set anything on your system to permissions 777. That is read/write/execute for anyone. Now that may be your private system, but you may one day work on production systems. You don't want to learn bad habits. NEVER use that set of permissions for any file.

Just want you to learn safe habits, not trying to brow beat you.